# Method returning a WinSock2 SOCKET doesn't compile

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock2

I want to create a method in c++ which returns a SOCKET Object, using WinSock2.

```
//header
#pragma once
class MyClass
{
public:
    SOCKET createSocket();

};

//definitions

#include "class.h"
#include <WinSock2.h>
SOCKET MyClass::createSocket()
{
    return SOCKET();
}
```

Yet, Visual Studio throws an error (E0147, C++ Die Deklaration ist nicht mit " (deklariert in Zeile 7 von)" kompatibel.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: The header file should have `#include <WinSock2.h>`

Comment: Include WinSock2 before the class.h or include it into the class.h. Generally speaking this slows down compilation, so consider including in precompiled headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <WinSock2.h>` is missing in the header. (Thanks Johnny Mopp)